# Get JSONObject out of URL and get Integer out of the JSON

Tags: java, json

I have this [URL](https://studev.groept.be/api/a21pt120/getPreviousID) with a JSON in it I would like to make a JSONObject of it and store the value in a variable named previousID.

[ { "id": "179" } ]

How can I create that JSONObject and get that int value out of it?

I can't make it work with the JSONObject so I tried it with a JSONArray but for some reason I always get the value 0 as return value.

```
    private int getPreviousID(Context context){
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    final int[] info = new int[1];
    JsonArrayRequest totalListRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, GET_LAST_URL,null,

            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    for (int i=0; i<response.length(); ++i) {
                        JSONObject o = null;
                        info[0] = 0;
                        try {
                            info[0] += response.getJSONObject(i).getInt("id");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Unable to communicate with the server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    queue.add(totalListRequest);
    return info[0];
}
```

Comment: your link is not fast to load. please add sample JSON file manully on the question.